# navigation between pages C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, navigation, screen

I’ve created a game where I have good player that is trying to run from the baddies. My game is working very well but my problem is that I don’t know how to create an end game screen.
When you start playing, the first screen you see (created blank page with xaml design) is Start Screen where you can click on “start” and navigate (using navigation frame with this guide : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages) to the main page – where the game is happening.
I want to create another screen or window that shows up whenever the game is over: you can win in the game if good player stayed with only one baddies or you can lose the game if baddie catches you. So how can I use inside an if condition a Navigate method? Do I need another event? (And which one) or there is another way to create end game screen, depending on the rules of the game?
Remember- in this case I don’t have 2 element (like buttons) that I can click on to go to the end game screen.

I have a class called Manager that responsible for all the game logics and checking if the game is over or not. In this code I’m checking the collusion between the baddies- and “removing” one if they collides on each other. This is one of the places that I want to add my If condition, to see if the game is over – and if it is – to navigate\present my end game screen:

```
    class Manager
{
    //claulating collision between baddies
    //checking each time if one of the baddies (loop 1) collides another (going throw the rest of the baddied - loop 2) 
    int x, y, t, l, width, height;

    public void baddiesCollision(Baddies[] baddiesArr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < baddiesArr.Length; i++)
        {
            x = (int)baddiesArr[i].ImgLeft; //represent the position of ImgLeft on the first to compare-baddie
            y = (int)baddiesArr[i].ImgTop; //represent the position of ImgTop on the first to compare-baddie
            width = baddiesArr[i].PlayerWidth;
            height = baddiesArr[i].PlayerHeight;
            for(int j=i+1; j<=baddiesArr.Length-1; j++)
            {
                t = (int)baddiesArr[j].ImgLeft; //represent the position of ImgLeft on the next to compare-baddie
                l = (int)baddiesArr[j].ImgTop; //represent the position of ImgTop on the next to compare-baddie
                if (x <= t && t < x + width && y <= l && l <= y + height)
                {
                    baddiesArr[j].badPlayer.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (x <= t + width && t + width <= x + width && y <= l && l <= y + height)
                {
                    baddiesArr[j].badPlayer.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (x <= t && t <= x + width && y <= l + height && l + height <= y + height)
                {
                    baddiesArr[j].badPlayer.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (x <= t + width && t + width <= x + width && y <= l + height && l + height <= y + height)
                {
                    baddiesArr[j].badPlayer.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
       **if(there is only one baddie that stayed --> go to End Game Screen)**
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what you are looking for, but if you wish to navigate between pages use following code:

Frame.Navigate(typeof(newPage));

Comment: Obviously, you create a new class, .xaml to navigate to before using this piece of code.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn’t work. If I’m adding to by code: Frame.Navigate(typeof(EndScreen)); (I’ve added a Blank page called EndScreen) I’m getting this message: “An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property ‘Frame.Navigate(Type)’ “
And I'm not sure what it means and how should I handle this.

Comment: Today i stumbled upon [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/using-the-navigationview-in-your-uwp-applications/ba-p/317200) Maybe this helps you.